# combobox not allowing to select the value again, once it selected

Tags: extjs

I am using combobox in my application, it allows me to select the value only single time, when I want to change my selection it does not allow me to select value again. It just open an and goes back. How to resolve this.

Code:

```
 {
                xtype:'combobox',
                style:'margin:10px;',
                fieldLabel: 'M Group(*)',
                editable:false,
                bodyStyle:'padding-left:10px;',
                store: GroupStore,
                valueField:'value',
                displayField:'name',
                multiSelect: false,
                name: 'GroupId',
                id:'MGroupId',
                queryMode: 'local',
                triggerAction: 'all',
                //disabled:true,
                emptyText:'Select Group',   
                listeners: {
                    expand : function(field, eOpts)
                    {                   
                        if(isFirst) {
                            inputJson.Unit.id = Id;                     
                            this.getStore().load({
                                  params: {jsonData: Ext.encode(inputJson)}
                            });                     
                            Ext.getCmp('MGroupId').setDisabled(false);
                            Ext.getCmp('MGroupId').setVisible(true);

                        }else{
                            Ext.getCmp('MGroupId').setDisabled(true);
                            Ext.getCmp('MGroupId').setVisible(false);

                        }

                    },              
                    select: function(combo, record, index) {    

                     this.getStore().each(function(r){                  

                         if(combo.getValue() == r.data['value'])
                         {
                            MGroupName = r.data['name'];                                                    
                         }
                     });

                  }
```

Comment: make sure you have set `displayField` & `ValueField` properties properly.

Comment: everything is in place it was working previously. but now it stops.

Comment: What version of Extjs is this?